# Stripping out Babel in Flask Jinja Template

Tags: flask, jinja2

I’m working with [this](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/microblog/blob/v0.23/app/templates/_post.html) tutorial which has the following lines:

```
            {% set user_link %}
                <span class="user_popup">
                    <a href="{{ url_for('main.user', username=post.author.username) }}">
                        {{ post.author.username }}
                    </a>
                </span>
            {% endset %}
            {{ _('%(username)s said %(when)s',
                    username=user_link, when=moment(post.timestamp).fromNow())  }}
```

It looks this was specifically because he uses Babel translate, which he talks about on his [blog](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xiii-i18n-and-l10n).

My question is, how can I make this work when I strip all the Babel code out, because I don’t need any translation, specifically the bit after end set.

This is the sort of thing I tried but could never get the replacement correct:

```
{{username, username=user_link }} said {{when,when=moment(post.timestamp).fromNow())}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{{ user_link }} said {{ moment(post.timestamp).fromNow() }}
```

The arguments after the string define the replacement map for the different keywords, so:

- `%(username)s` will be replaced by `user_link`, because `username=user_link`
- `$(when)s` will be replaced by `moment(post.timestamp).fromNow()`, because `when=moment(post.timestamp).fromNow()`

The `s` ending the `$(placeholder)s` is there to indicate that the placeholder should be considered as a **s**tring.